# Strikethrough Text in a Merea-Frameowrk Site?

Tags: kramdown, morea-framework

Strikethrough doesn't work for me in a morea framework markdown page, e.g.,

> ~~Strikethrough~~

is presented with the raw tildes.

I see [here](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/304) that this was already fixed in kramdown (the markdown engine used in morea). Should I update kramdown? how then? other ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating Jekyll and Kramdown to their latest releases, strikethrough works. Here's an example Morea site illustrating strikethrough:

http://morea-framework.github.io/morea-news-page-example/

The home.md page source is here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/morea-framework/morea-news-page-example/master/src/morea/morea/home.md

To make this work correctly I updated gem, jekyll, and kramdown:

```
% sudo gem update --system
Password:
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.4
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.4
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.4
Installing darkfish documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.4
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.4
Installing RubyGems 2.6.4
RubyGems 2.6.4 installed
Parsing documentation for rubygems-2.6.4
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-2.6.4

% sudo gem update jekyll
Updating installed gems
Updating jekyll
Fetching: jekyll-3.1.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-3.1.6
Parsing documentation for jekyll-3.1.6
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-3.1.6
Installing darkfish documentation for jekyll-3.1.6
Parsing documentation for jekyll-3.1.6
Gems updated: jekyll

% sudo gem update kramdown
Updating installed gems
Updating kramdown
Fetching: kramdown-1.11.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed kramdown-1.11.1
Parsing documentation for kramdown-1.11.1
Installing ri documentation for kramdown-1.11.1
Installing darkfish documentation for kramdown-1.11.1
Parsing documentation for kramdown-1.11.1
Gems updated: kramdown
```

Maybe you only need to update kramdown, but this seemed like a good opportunity to update Jekyll as well.